# How to manually scale data to a normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I do data normalization as:

```py
X = ( X - X.mean(axis=0) ) / X.std(axis=0)
```

But some features of `X` have 0 variance. It gives me `Runtime error for ZeroDivision.`

I know we can normalize using "StandardScalar" class from sklearn. But **how can I normalize data by myself from scratch if std=0** ?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote sklearn documentation for [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> Per feature relative scaling of the data to achieve zero mean and unit variance. Generally this is calculated using np.sqrt(var_). If a variance is zero, we can’t achieve unit variance, and the data is left as-is, giving a scaling factor of 1.

Therefore, like what the other answer said, you can omit the standard deviation term and just do `X - X.mean(axis=0)` when standard deviation is 0. However this only works if the whole of `X` has 0 standard deviation.

To make this work where you have a mix of values with some std dev and values that don't, use this instead:

```py
std = X.std(axis=0)
std = np.where(std == 0, 1, std)
X = ( X - X.mean(axis=0) ) / std
```

This code checks if standard deviation is zero for each row of values in axis 0, and replaces them with 1 if true.

Answer (score 1):

If standard deviation is 0 for a particular feature, than all of its values are identical. In this case `X = X - X.mean(axis=0)` should suffice. This would give you 0 mean and 0 standardeviation.